# Play videos in a different screen without showing desktop environment and cursor interactions in Gnome

Tags: x11, gnome, video, software-rec

I'm editing videos for a live music event. There's a video for each song. I'll have a projector and each song will have a video playing in a big screen behind the artists.

I have the length for each song so the videos length match. The time between songs is variable, since the musicians will be talking in between.

Is there any software I can use to send a video to a screen, play it, and show a full screen image between videos without the screen showing Gnome's desktop environment and the mouse cursor selecting videos/moving windows, etc? I mean, using my laptop's screen for interactions and make the projector's screen just show the videos when the videos are playing, and a fixed image in between videos.

Comment: That's more of a question of how to configure Gnome. Managing what gets shown on each screen is the job of the window manager and desktop environment, not the job of an application such as a video player.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great way to do this if you have the luxury of having two computers. Two computers can be especially practical if you install one (the one that is driving the video) near the projector which could be in an inconvenient location, and the other one (call it the remote control, it can be a cheap laptop) where you need to run the show.

On the video driver computer, stop or uninstall any display manager such as `xdm` or `lightdm`. Then, from the remote control laptop, `ssh` in to the driver computer.

Optionally, start `screen` so that everything will continue working in case your network connection to the other computer breaks during the show:

```
screen
```

Now start the X server manually:

```
X &
```

Then set your environment to use that newly-started X server:

```
DISPLAY=:0
export DISPLAY
```

Use something like this to make sure the default "sandbox" X server root window background will never show through:

```
xsetroot -solid black
# or else a static image:
pngtopnm hello.png | xli -onroot stdin
```

You may find it helpful to run this to hide the mouse pointer (since there's no mouse connected to that computer):

```
unclutter &
```

When the time comes, show your videos:

```
mplayer xxx.avi  # or whatever you're using.
```

Since there is nothing at all running on that computer except the X server, possibly a static image, and your video player, not even a window manager, you can be absolutely sure that no part of any desktop environment will ever "leak". Plus, the only thing you need to have available in your control location is a network connection to the other computer; that's easier than backhauling video.